# How to handle reordering lists in iOS?

Tags: ios, lists, drag-n-drop, ordering

I have an iOS application that looks something like this:

[image: Home layout]

Every row is tappable and as you can see, its pretty tall, only 4 can fit fully in the viewport. Also, every row has a left and right swipe action. What would be the best solution for users to reorder this list?

I have 3 solutions in my mind:

1. Tap&hold to reorder, just like the homescreen icons
2. Use the settings page. I'll create a new section with a simple
   drag&drop list of the same items that are on the homepage, like
   this:

   [image: Settings reorder]
3. Add a new icon next to + like Edit, and that will show the reorder
   icon on each item.

I have problems with each of these solutions. The first one might be hard to discover and if the user has a longer list that does not fit in one viewport, reordering might be an issue. The second one also seems a bit weird because its on another menu. The third one has the same issue as the first, and also two icons next to it might look bad in the top right corner.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: #1 is good if it's ok if lots of people don't find the feature (ie more of a power user thing), #2 seems weird but I could see it if the list was made of categories that you'd only ever sort once, #3 is a decent option if you need most users to actually sort IMO

Answer (score 1):

You can use the swipe left or right option to have reorder list option and if you already have the swipe reserved for some other options then you can use it in same side as I showed in the attached image. If the user wants to reorder the list up by one or two steps then they can easily move it by taping the arrow up or down otherwise they can enter the value in the text box. This is my opinion.

[image]

Comment: This model isn't intuitive to me since the act swiping side-to-side doesn't match the end result of moving the item up or down. Also, if I'm reading it right, passatgt mentioned in his post that each row already has a swipe action.

Comment: Unconventional but interesting idea